# PyGame, How to clean up Old Sprites

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I've been working with Python and PyGame days ago, and i noticed that when i move the player in my game, ***it will blit over itself again and again while moving, leaving a tail,*** is there any way i can clean up all the old sprites that the player left while moving?
I tried bliting the background again while moving to remove them, but that was frustrating in a point. Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why was it frustrating? Just clean (copy background of) the las position before drawing the new one. Could you post some code? ie: your main loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Does PyGame Trail the Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049561/why-does-pygame-trail-the-image)

Answer (score 1):

Just call `window.fill([0, 0, 0])` each time in your main loop.  Where the `window` is your `pygame.display.set_mode()` main surface.  If you have any questions, just comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your code in a different order
or probably it is because you put the line of code that puts the image on the screen in a loop instead of the line that draws the whole window (screen)

example:

```py
import pygame as pg
win = pg.display.set_mode((width, height)) # the set up of the window
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group() # this is the group where the sprites live 

all_sprites.draw(win) # this draws the whole window
```

Comment: How is this answer different from or better than the one posted by @Remolten _**8 years ago**_? Try to avoid bumping up old questions.

Comment: The reason why mine is different is because i am asking the python developer to rearrange their code by putting the line of code that prints the image on the screen out of any loop and move the line that draws the screen in the loop. Instead of, calling the set up of the window and putting it in the loop